# Typeahead result formatting

Tags: jsonp, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead, typeahead.js

Trying to use Typeahead and struggling with JSON formatting (which I have no control over).

`{ name="Long Island", type="2", id="1234"}`

Here is my JS

```
$autocomplete.typeahead({
name: 'location',
remote: {
    url: 'http://pathtomysite.com/%QUERY?',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    filter: function (parsedResponse) {
        console.log(parsedResponse);
        return parsedResponse;
    }
},
template: [
    '<p class="repo-name">{{name}}</p>',
    '<p class="repo-description">{{id}}</p>'
].join(''),
engine: Hogan
```

});

So the request works and it returns objects in the console, but the typeahead visual dropdown just says 'undefined'.

So I am guessing I need to do something with datums?

I've tried using Hogan templating but nothing is appearing in the drop down.

Not sure if JSONP is this issue? The request has a load of characters prepended, see the JS tab
http://jsbin.com/aPOZohi/1/edit

So yeah, where am I going wrong?

Once I get it returning data, I have another formatting question for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Xeevis's answer is almost correct.

First: the "many characters prepended" are jQuery's way of doing JSONP internally when doing cross-domain request.

Second: Xeevis is right, the problem is `valueKey`, but not only `valueKey`. The response has to be an array of object, each containing a member by the name specified by `valueKey`. So set `valueKey` to `"name"`, but also return an array:

```
filter: function (parsedResponse) {
    console.log(parsedResponse);
    return parsedResponse.locations;
}
```

Comment: yep that sorted it,thank you! Now, I have another question which I'll write up now...

Comment: follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722627/typeahead-templating-if-else

Answer (score 0):

Typeahead is by default expecting "value" in datum. Change valueKey to "name".

```
$autocomplete.typeahead({
    valueKey: 'name',
    name: 'location',
    remote: { ... }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work either.

http://jsbin.com/aPOZohi/2/edit

The console.log returns the correct stuff, just nothing showing visually. No errors either.

Hogan is definitely included ( <script src="http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/builds/2.0.0/hogan-2.0.0.js"></script>
)