# Typeahead templating, if/else

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead, typeahead.js, hogan.js

thanks for the help on this question: [Typeahead result formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704700/typeahead-result-formatting), this is a follow up.

My JSON looks like

`[{ name="Long Island", type="2", id="1234"}, { name="New York", type="1", id="5678"}]`

In the drop down list I need to be able to seperate type 1 from type 2, so

**Type 1 heading**

type 1 item

type 1 item*

**Type 2 heading**

type 2 item

type 2 item

If there are no results for type 1, then don't show the heading. Same for type 2.

Is this possible with typeahead and a templating engine? I'm using Hogan but I'm not fussy.

Answer (score 1):

The "Typeahead" way of doing this is to separate your dataset into 2 datasets, one that will only return "type 1" items and another that will return only "type 2" items. In typeahead, each dataset can have its own `header`, which will behave exactly the way you want it.

```
$autocomplete.typeahead([{
    name: 'location 1',
    remote: {
        url: 'http://pathtomysite.com/%QUERY?type=1',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        valueKey: 'name'
        filter: function (parsedResponse) { return parsedResponse.locations; }
    },
    template: [
        '<p class="repo-name">{{name}}</p>',
        '<p class="repo-description">{{id}}</p>'
    ].join(''),
    header: '<b>Type 1</b>'
    engine: Hogan
}, {
    name: 'location 2',
    remote: {
        url: 'http://pathtomysite.com/%QUERY??type=2',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        valueKey: 'name'
        filter: function (parsedResponse) { return parsedResponse.locations; }
    },
    template: [
        '<p class="repo-name">{{name}}</p>',
        '<p class="repo-description">{{id}}</p>'
    ].join(''),
    header: '<b>Type 2</b>'
    engine: Hogan
}])
```

Comment: That doesn't work as it means an additional query on the JSON which I can't control at all.

Comment: There are several workarounds, I'll write more when near a PC.

Comment: Note that the above code applies to a Typeahead.js version prior to v0.10.x

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't have control over the JSON part, you have 2 options:

**Option 1**

Use 2 datasets, with the *same* query. In one of them, the `filter` will only return "type 1" entries, in the other the `filter` will only return "type 2" answers.

That's twice the calls to the JSON, so twice the load on your server. The client side will not see a delay, though, as the queries are concurrent.

That's a hackish solution, but OTOH it's clean (client-side-wise), and requires very little code.

**Option 2**

Use only 1 dataset, and so some work in your `filter`. Basically, return an array with an entry for the "type 1" header, then all the type 1 entries, then an entry for the "type 2" header, then all the type 2 entries.

The array is an array of objects. Each object will also have a `class` member. In the entries for the "type 1" and "type 2" headers set the class to `"header"` or something along the lines, and:

1) Have your template include the class.
2) Have your CSS make the class unselectable, unclickable, and styled the way you want it.

I like option #1 better.